# Typo3: Post List

Tags: typo3, posts

I'm working on a magazine webpage and the static version is pretty much ready by now.

Now I was wondering what would be the easiest way to create a post list, so a user can add a new post to that list.

For each post of that list, a page should be created, of course containing the text and images the user defines.
Also a goal would be, to be able to list all posts on one page where the user can click the one he want to read.

I've discovered the blog extension but I'm not sure if that is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension tx_news is probably good for you, hope it helps :)

Comment: Is there a way to filter for the key when searching for an extension in the typo3 backend? secondary issue...

Comment: all I know is you can use the ext key as a search term. "News" is the ext key of tx_news. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look for the extension `just_news`: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/just_news/